# If a local morphism of rings induces an isomorphism on associated graded rings, must it have been an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

I have local morphism of local rings $f:(R,\mathfrak{m}) \to (S,\mathfrak{n})$, (i.e. $f(\mathfrak{m}^r) \subset \mathfrak{n}^s$ for all $s$) such that $\mathrm{gr}(f):\mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{m}}(R) = R/\mathfrak{m} \oplus \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2 \oplus \cdots \to \mathrm{gr}_{\mathfrak{n}}(S)$ is an isomorphism of graded rings. Can I conclude $f$ was an isomorphism to begin with? I feel like this should be clear one way or the other but I don't see it. Rings are not Noetherian but can be assumed complete if that matters/makes it true. If not true, are there any general conditions on the rings that would make this hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you drop the completeness requirement, you have the inclusion: $$\mathbb{R}\hookrightarrow\frac{\mathbb{R}[t_\lambda|\lambda\in \mathbb{R}^{>0}]}{\langle t_\lambda t_\mu- t_{\lambda+\mu}|\lambda,\mu\in \mathbb{R}^{>0},t_\lambda |\lambda\geq1 \rangle}$$

Note the RHS is a quotient of a polynomial ring (not formal power series).  The maximal ideal $m$ is generated by the $t_\lambda$.  To see see it is unique, note that all its elements are nilpotent, so any element outside of $m$ has the form $\lambda+\alpha$ with $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}, \lambda\neq0$ and $\alpha$ nilpotent, so $\lambda+\alpha$ is invertible.

Finally note that $m^2=m$ as $t_\lambda={t_{\frac\lambda2}}^2$.  Thus applying ${\rm gr}_m$ to the RHS just returns $\mathbb{R}$.

For any Cauchy sequence in the RHS, there exists $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ such that eventually all elements $x_j$ of the sequence have the form $\lambda+\alpha_j$, with $\alpha_j\in m$.  Then we have $\alpha_j\in m^i$ for all $i$ so the sequence converges to $\lambda$.  However Cauchy sequences converge to more than one limit.

---

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring.  Define a sequence in $R$ to be Cauchy if for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, its residues modulo $\mathfrak{m}^n$ are eventually constant.  Say that $R$ is $complete$ if every Cauchy sequence has a unique limit.

Lemma: If $R$ is complete and $f\colon (R,\mathfrak{m}) \to (S,\mathfrak{n})$ is a local morphism, and
gr$(f)$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.

Proof: gr$(f)$ being injective means precisely that for all $i\in \mathbb{N}$, if $f(x)\in \mathfrak{n}^i$ then $x\in \mathfrak{m}^i$. In particular if $f(x)=0$ then $x\in\mathfrak{m}^i$ for all $i$ and the constant sequence $x,x,x,\cdots$ converges to $0$.  However it also converges to $x$, so as $R$ is complete, we have $x=0$. $[]$

Lemma: If $R,S$ are both complete and $f\colon (R,\mathfrak{m}) \to (S,\mathfrak{n})$ is a local morphism, and gr$(f)$ is surjective, then $f$ is surjective.

Proof: If gr$(f)$ is surjective, then for any $y\in S$ we can find $x_0\in R$ with $y-f(x_0)\in \mathfrak{n}$. Then we may find $x_1\in \mathfrak{m}$ so that $y-f(x_0)-f(x_1)\in \mathfrak{n}^2$.  Thus $y-f(x_0+x_1)\in \mathfrak{n}^2$. Repeating we may find $x_2\in \mathfrak{m}^2$ so that $y-f(x_0+x_1+x_2)\in\mathfrak{n}^3$, and so on.

The sequence $x_0,x_0+x_1,x_0+x_1+x_2,\cdots$ is Cauchy so converges to $x\in R$.  Thus for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $y-f(x)\in \mathfrak{n}^i$.  In particular, the constant sequence $f(x),f(x),f(x),\cdots$ converges to $y$.  However it also converges to $f(x)$ so as $S$ is complete we have that $y=f(x)$.[]

Combining these results, we have that if $R,S$ are complete, then gr$(f)$ an isomorphism implies that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do you think it is true if the rings are complete?

Comment: I have seen $complete$ defined as both "every Cauchy sequence converges" and "every Cauchy sequence converges to a unique limit".  I have gone with the latter which is equivalent to the definition given in https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0323.   In any case the rings in my original example satisfied the first property but not the second, and if rings satisfy the second property then your statement is true (see edited answer).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. One way I tried to prove this was passing to the "Hausdorffication" of the ring, in which case your proof does it. This kills counterexamples involving rings with ideals of definition $I$ such that $I^2=I$. I guess this is the only 'obstruction'.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray} f \,\,{\rm surjective}&\implies& {\rm gr}(f) {\,\,\rm surjective},
\\ f \,\, {\rm injective}&\quad\not \!\!\!\!\implies& {\rm gr}(f) \,\,{\rm injective},
\\f \,\,{\rm an \,\, isomorphism}&\implies& {\rm gr}(f) \,\,{\rm bijective},\\\\
{\rm gr}(f) \,\, {\rm injective}&\implies& \bar{f} \,\,{\rm injective},\\ {\rm gr}(f) \,\,{\rm bijective}&\implies& \bar{f} \,\,{\rm an \,\,isomorphism},\\\\\bar{f} \,\,{\rm surjective}&\implies& {\rm gr}(f) {\,\,\rm surjective},\\\bar{f} \,\, {\rm injective}&\quad\not \!\!\!\!\implies& {\rm gr}(f) \,\,{\rm injective}.\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Above are some implications I found.  The fifth one gives an alternative answer to your original question.

Comment: Actually you can add $${\rm gr}(f)\,\, {\rm surjective}\,\,\implies \bar{f} \,\, {\rm surjective}$$ to that.  (Sorry I am very bad at letting things go - you didn't even ask about this).